# Google chrome status pending after 302 redirect

Tags: http, google-chrome, video, amazon-s3

I'm using an HTML5 video player that works well for the most part - except when it comes to Chrome. It's a straightforward video element containing a source element, resulting in the browser making a GET request for the video file (XXX.mp4) to a thin server, which returns a 302 redirect to the location of the MP4 file on Amazon S3. Chrome usually (but not always) gets mired in a (pending) status when it's expected to make the second request for the file from amazonaws.com, so the video never shows up. The request header looks like this:

```
GET /api/s3/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://xxxxxxx/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: rack.session=XXXXXXXXXX
Range: bytes=0-
```

Thin's response header looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
cache-control: public, no-store, max-age=0
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET
location: https://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1391823471&Signature=enXXXXXXXXXX
content-length: 0
set-cookie: rack.session=XXXXXXXXXX; path=/; expires=Sat, 08 Feb 2014 01:47:51 -0000; HttpOnly
x-content-type-options: nosniff
connection: keep-alive
server: thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2014 01:17:51 GMT
```

I've been doing a lot of Googling but haven't found a solution as yet. Any help would be much appreciated.